# Enable mod_rewrite on OpenSuSE 11.04

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a problem on OpenSuSE 11.04. I configured apache and enabled mod_rewrite but it doesn't working. on every php file I get 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file? If not, open it and add the following lines at the end of the file. You may need to replace `/srv/www/htdocs` with the path to your server's 'htdocs' or 'public_html' directory:

```
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache and check your URL again. If you still see errors, try creating an .htaccess file in your `htdocs` folder to force the base directory. This seems to help sometimes if your hosting company puts their VPS boxes behind another server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

If this still fails to fix things for you, check the logs at `/var/log/apache2/access_log` and `/var/log/apache2/error_log` to see what's going wrong. You can also use [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to get more information about where the URL rewrite fails.

Comment: Man i was since yesterday trying to understand why my mode-rewrite was not working... and i tried your solution to put this piece of code in my httpd.conf: DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs"> Options +FollowSymLinks AllowOverride all Order deny,allow Allow from all
</Directory> And my Codeigniter started to work like a charm... thanks for the tip!!